# name 'cursor' is not defined.Python27

Tags: mysql, python

Hola que tal tengo una duda la cual en el script que tengo, eh definido la conexion y el cursor pero al correr ese fragmento de codigo me da el error name 'cursor' is not defined.

Espero explicarme.

En la primera linea de la función hago la conexión a la base de datos y en la siguiente linea estoy leyendo un archivo csv el cual esta dentro de la carpeta ya que ese archivo es necesaria su lectura, la informacion de este archivo no esta dentro de la base de datos, en la linea siguiente creo el cursor para poder extraer la informacion desde la ba cual es la que estoy tratando de acceder.
Espero que me puedan ayudar..
Gracias de antemano!!

Aqui esta el codigo que me genera el error

```
def test():

        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",passwd="1234",db="Horario")
        cursor = db.cursor() #executing conecction


        courses = []
        tablacourses=pd.read_csv('courses.csv',header=1,error_bad_lines=True)

        for c in tablacourses.itertuples():
            courses.append( c[1] )

        profs = []
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sised_profesor WHERE estatus='ACTIVO'") # execute  query
        datos = cursor.fetchall() # get data
        tablaDatos = pd.DataFrame(list(datos),columns=titulos)

        for p in tablaDatos.itertuples():
            profs.append(p[1])

        times = []

        cursor.execute("SELECT id_horario_docencia FROM sised_horario_docencia ORDER BY GROUP ") # execute query
        datos = cursor.fetchall() # get data
        tablaDatos = pd.DataFrame(list(datos),columns=titulos) # save data to dataframe
        for t in tablaDatos.itertuples():
            times.append(p[1])

        rooms = []
        cursor.execute("SELECT id_espacio FROM sised_espacio ORDER BY GROUP ID")   # execute query 
        datos = cursor.fetchall() #  get data
        tablaDatos = pd.DataFrame(list(datos),columns=titulos) # save data to dataframe

        for r in tablaDatos.itertuples():
            rooms.append(r[1])
```

Comment: ¿Qué línea te da el error? ¿Será que lo que no está definido es `db.cursor()`?

Comment: Ese error me genera cuando hago una consulta en myql, en la conexion estoy definiendo la creacion de un cursor para poder hacer la consulta.